# What does ... (ellipsis) as one and only function parameter in a function prototype mean in C++?

Tags: c++, function, variadic-functions, ellipsis, variadic

I´ve came across a function declaration, like:

```
int vsa_d(...);
```

with `...` as one and only parameter.

I know that with an ellipsis, we can refer to multiple objects, but to what does the `...` refer to here?

- What does that mean and for what is it meant for?
- To what `...` gets evaluated by the compiler?
- Could the ellipsis be used also as a function argument, at the invocation of a function?

---

I´ve found here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments under "*Notes*":

> In the C programming language, at least one named parameter must appear before the ellipsis parameter, so printz(...); is not valid. In C++, this form is allowed even though the arguments passed to such function are not accessible, and is commonly used as the fallback overload in SFINAE, exploiting the lowest priority of the ellipsis conversion in overload resolution.

So, it shall be used for anything like a "*fallback overload*" in "*SFINAE*".

What does that mean?

Comment: It does the same as it does in C. In C++ there are better options so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I´ll cite something what `ve found to that topic: "*In the C programming language, at least one named parameter must appear before the ellipsis parameter, so printz(...); is not valid.*"  - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments under "*Notes*".

Comment: @JesperJuhl After that citation, it isn´t valid in C to code in this way and that is also a reason why I explicitly asked the question for C++. Why do you are certain that this will be valid in C?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I made an C experiment and tried to compile it with gcc; the result: `error: ISO C requires a named argument before ‘...’`

Comment: @JesperJuhl It seems to be used for a C++-own error handling or proofing kind of thing: `and is commonly used as the fallback overload in SFINAE, exploiting the lowest priority of the ellipsis conversion in overload resolution. `

Comment: if you don't understand how to use SFINAE, i recommend this book for u "C++ templates:the complete guide, 2nd edition, David Vandevoorde, et al".  Chap8 section 4 of it explains clearly how the ... argument is used in SFINAE for "fallback overload"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `...` argument is used as a catch-all in some SFINAE constructions.

Here is an except from the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/1718575) in a question about writing a type trait `has_helloworld<T>` that detects whether a type T has a member `helloworld`:

```
template <typename T>
class has_helloworld
{
    typedef char one;
    struct two { char x[2]; };

    template <typename C> static one test( typeof(&C::helloworld) ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);    

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << has_helloworld<Hello>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_helloworld<Generic>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works in the following way:  if `typeof(&T::helloworld)` exists and is a well-formed, then at the site `test<T>(0)`, the constant `0` is converted to a pointer-to-member(-function) and that overload is selected.  The size of the return type is one.

If `typeof(&T::helloworld)` *does not exist*, then that overload is not in the potential overload set, and the fallback `test(...)` is selected as the overload.  The size of the return type is two.

The `test(...)` overload has the nice property that it is always the *worst*-matching, last-selected overload.  This means it can serve as the "fallback default" in such constructions.

Comment: I think it's worth noting `typeof` is a GCC extension, not standard, but `decltype` would work instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
int vsa_d(...); // can take any number of arguments
```

Here, `vsa_d` can take any number of arguments.

> So, it shall be used for anything like a "fallback overload" in
>   "SFINAE".
>
> What does that mean?

Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_f {
  template <typename U, typename = decltype(std::declval<U&>().f())>
  static std::true_type foo(U);

  static std::false_type foo(...);

  using type = typename decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()))::type;
};

struct a {
  void f(){}
};
```

Here `foo` has two overloads:

```
template <typename U, typename = decltype(std::declval<U&>().f())>
static std::true_type foo(U);
```

If the expression `decltype(std::declval<U&>().f()` is valid, then whatever we called `has_f` with has indeed a function `f` and this overload will be chosen.

Otherwise, the non-template member function will be chosen

```
static std::false_type foo(...);
```

Because it has the lowest priority.

---

Calling

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_f<a>::type();
```

gives

```
true
```